# creating a file using StreamWriter

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 public void Convert_Xls_To_CSV(string sourceFile, string targetFile)
{

   try
   {
      // wrtr = new StreamWriter(targetFile);
       StreamWriter wrtr = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(targetFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read));
       DataTable dt = ConvertExcelFileToDataTable(sourceFile);
       for (int x = 0; x < dt.Rows.Count; x++)
       {

           string rowString = "";
           for (int y = 0; y < dt.Columns.Count; y++)
           {
               rowString += "\"" + dt.Rows[x][y].ToString() + "\",";
           }

           wrtr.WriteLine(rowString);
       }

           wrtr.Close();
           wrtr.Dispose();
   }

   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       Error_lb.Text = ex.Message;
   }
}
```

I'm using this function to write a csvfile.the targetFile is not created.

```
StreamWriter wrtr = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(targetFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read));
```

should this line create the file if it's not exist  ?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Why don't you just try it and find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplify your call to;

`sw = new StreamWriter(fileNameToSave, false)`

From *MSDN*;

**StreamWriter(String, Boolean) -   Initializes a new instance of the StreamWriter class for the specified file by using the default encoding and buffer size. If the file exists, it can be either overwritten or appended to. If the file does not exist, this constructor creates a new file.**

Also, your usage seems similar to something I have some code for;

```
var saveFile = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFile.InitialDirectory = Properties.Settings.Default.systemLogPath;
saveFile.RestoreDirectory = true;
saveFile.Title = "Filename to log to";
saveFile.Filter = "Text (*.txt)|*.txt|Log (*.log)|*.log";
if (saveFile.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
   using (var sw = new StreamWriter(saveFile.FileName, false))
   {
       foreach (var item in messages.Items)
       {
           sw.Write(item.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
       }
   }
}
```

Maybe that can be of use to you as well.

Answer (score 1):

Please [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h0z48dh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Your second parameter refers to the [`FileMode` Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which says the following about `FileMode.Create`:

> Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. If the file already exists, it will be overwritten.